# JasperReport Server vs JasperReports IO

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I was wondering what is difference between Jasper reports server and jasper reports IO ? In the official website it indicates that JR-IO has a rest API to generate reports. But as far as I know JR-Server also has a Rest API which has similar functionality. So what's the difference between those two products?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JasperReports IO is created with scalability in mind from ground up. It is a reporting-only specialized REST API based service.

Just like the JasperReports Library offers reporting functionality to Java applications as a Java API packaged in a JAR file, the JRIO offers the same reporting functionality but in the form of a REST API that can be used to add reporting functionality in service based architectures, regardless of their development/running platform.

JasperReports IO takes care of reporting only and does not have any security of its own and needs to be embedded into parent applications that provide the end user front end. JasperReports IO is not normally used on its own as it does not actually have a UI and needs to be used as a component/service inside some other application.

Actually, in the latest release of JasperReports Server, the report execution can be delegated to a scalable instance of JasperReports IO that runs side-by-side with JRS itself, improving performance and optimizing resource consumption.

Comment: Thank you for that. So you are saying main difference between JR Server and JR IO is that JR Server offers an UI component whereas JR IO is only deals with  executing the report generation logic ?

Comment: No, the UI is not the only difference. JRS has repository management, users and roles manangement, permissions, report scheduler, domains, adhoc designer, dashboards, multi-tenancy and other features. Your question was only about the REST API for generating reports and indeed the two products expose a similar one. But then my question to you is: Is this REST API the only thing you need? What about the others that I have listed above in this comment?

Comment: Ok Teodor thank you so much for your answer. We've just started to use JR in my organization and I wanted to be aware of the options this product is offering. I think it would be better if there are more tutorials and informative videos on platforms like YouTube. It seem like JR is not as popular as other BI tools. I would like an open source tool to be more accessible. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: By the way maybe it's my igronorance but I didn't find it as accessible as other tools like Power BI or Google Data Studio. There are tons of tutorials and informative videos on YouTube and it's a lot easier to get started with these tools.